# How select TOP N% individual in a group with repeated measures in r

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with some individual, like this:

```
Animal Score Weight
John     5     4
John     5     3
John     5     3
Peter    3     2
Peter    3     2
Louis    4     2
Louis    4     4
Louis    4     1
Sammy    3     2
Sammy    3     2
Sammy    3     2
John     1     5
John     1     5
John     1     5
```

And I would like to select the TOP 40% of the best animals, based on the score, and maintaining all measures of the TOP 40%, like this:

```
   Animal Score Weight
    John     5     4
    John     5     3
    John     5     3
    Louis    4     2
    Louis    4     4
    Louis    4     1
```

I tried this code:

```
 top40=subset(df, Score > quantile(Score, prob = 1 - 40/100))
```

but didn't work, I selected based only on the Score value, like this:

```
 Animal Score Weight
    John     5     4
    John     5     3
    John     5     3
    Louis    4     2
```

Comment: Try: `subset(df, Score > quantile(Score, probs = 0.6))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each animal has a single score which is repeated, and you want to select animals whose score is in the top 40%, one option is

```
subset(df, Score > quantile(unique(Score), 1 - 40/100))

#    Animal Score Weight
# 1:   John     5      4
# 2:   John     5      3
# 3:   John     5      3
# 4:  Louis     4      2
# 5:  Louis     4      4
# 6:  Louis     4      1
```

If you don't use `unique` (as in all the other answers currently), you get what I would think is an unexpected result. Without `unique`, the animals in the "top 40% by Score" change even when the scores are the same, just because some animals have more rows.

```
df[c(rep(1, 10), 2:nrow(df)),] %>% 
        filter(
                Score > Score %>% quantile(0.4)
        )
#    Animal Score Weight
# 1    John     5      4
# 2    John     5      4
# 3    John     5      4
# 4    John     5      4
# 5    John     5      4
# 6    John     5      4
# 7    John     5      4
# 8    John     5      4
# 9    John     5      4
# 10   John     5      4
# 11   John     5      3
# 12   John     5      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
animals %>% 
        filter(
                Score > Score %>% quantile(0.4)
        )
```

BTW, `animals` is your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```r
n <- nrow(data)
head(data[order(data$Score, decreasing = TRUE) , ] , round(n*0.4) )
```

Comment: I appreciate, but is the same situation.