# Filter based on quantile in grouped data structure

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, transform, summarization

I have a variable that has the same value for all lines of a user, the maximum score reached in a game. I now want to filter the data set so that only those users remain in it that are above the 75% quantile of the variable max_score. I want to keep my basic record formatting, so I can't work with summarize.

Here is an example dataset:

```
da <- data.frame(user = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), max_score=as.numeric(c(150,150,150,100,100,100,75,75,75)))

da
  user max_score
1    1       150
2    1       150
3    1       150
4    2       100
5    2       100
6    2       100
7    3        75
8    3        75
9    3        75
```

I have tried the following:

```
da2= da %>% group_by(user) %>% filter(max(max_score) > quantile(max(max_score), .75))
```

...but it does not work.

Comment: You have only unique value for `max_score` per each user.  What do you expect

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't know how to solve this issue in a different way...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761382/how-select-top-n-individual-in-a-group-with-repeated-measures-in-r/56761697#56761697

Answer (score 0):

What's the expected output you'd like? Assuming it's:

```
user max_score
1    150
```

```
da2 <- 
  da %>% 
  filter(max_score >= as.numeric(quantile(max(da$max_score), .75))) %>%
  unique()
```

If not, happy to help further.

Comment: This doesn't compute any quantile*, it just returns the rows whose score is equal to the maximum score. *Technically this computes the quantile of a single number, the max of `max_score`, but the "quantile" there is just the number itself so the quantile function doesn't do anything (This filter would do the same thing `filter(max_score == max(max_score))`)

Comment: Do you have a solution to this, IceCreamToucan?

Comment: I think you want `da %>% filter(max_score > quantile(unique(max_score), 0.75))` (possibly with unique added at the end)